# report.jrxml columnfooter to be shown below the details section

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I have report.jrxml report generated from my application. Its only a one page report. I set the column footer and it is set at the end of the page and not immediately after the detail section. I have only couple of rows to be listed and I want the columnfooter to display immediately after the 2 rows of data.

I searched for a solution for this and they mention something about changing  the property to floatcolumn header. I am not sure how you do that? I am writing this report.rxml from my IDE. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: post your jrxml file for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the Jasper Studio IDE.
In any case, you said you need the column footer to float i.e. change its position with the height of the Detail band.

You can find the property in the Report root node properties. In that go to `Pagination`, and there is the `Float Column Footer` property.

Otherwise, you can set the  isFloatColumnFooter="true" attribute in the root node `jasperReport` of the JRXML.